# populating javaFX ListView throws exception

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am writing a javaFX application that contains a `ListView`. My attempt to populate the list view on initialization and with a button click is throwing an exception and due to my newbieness to javaFx I was not able to find a solution. Please help me out in finding out why, Thanks.

FXML documnet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane fx:id="root_borderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="405.0" prefWidth="720.0" stylesheets="@styles/style.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="managefilesclientnetbeans.FXMLDocumentController">
    <left>
        <VBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <GridPane>
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                    <children>
                        <Label fx:id="listLabel" text="Available files" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" />
                        <Button fx:id="refreshButton" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#onRefreshButtonClicked" text="Button" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" />
                    </children>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
                    </padding>
                </GridPane>
                <ListView prefHeight="286.0" prefWidth="166.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </left>
    <center>
        <GridPane>
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            </rowConstraints>
            <children>
                <Pane fx:id="previewPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <HBox fx:id="controlsPane" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="10.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <children>
                        <Button fx:id="downloadButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Download" />
                        <Button fx:id="uploadButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Upload" />
                    </children>
                    <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                    </GridPane.margin>
                </HBox>
            </children>
        </GridPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

controller class

```
package managefilesclientnetbeans;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import managefilesclientnetbeans.sime.seven.ClientHandler;


public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler();
    ObservableList<String> content;

    @FXML
    public Label listLabel;    
    @FXML
    public BorderPane root_borderPane;
    @FXML
    public Button refreshButton;
    @FXML
    public ListView<String> filesListView;
    @FXML
    public Button downloadButton;
    @FXML
    public Button uploadButton;
    @FXML
    public Pane previewPane;
    @FXML
    public Pane controlsPane;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        assert root_borderPane != null : "fx:id=\"root_boarderPane\" was not "
                + "injected check the FXML file";
        assert refreshButton != null : "refreshButton was not injected, check"
                + " your FXML file";
        assert previewPane != null : "previewPane was not injected, check"
                + " your FXML file";
        assert controlsPane != null : "controlsPane was not injected, check"
                + " your FXML file";
        assert downloadButton != null : "downloadButton was not injected, check"
                + " your FXML file";
        assert uploadButton != null : "uploadButton was not injected, check"
                + " your FXML file";
        assert listLabel != null : "listLabel was not initialized, check "
                + "your FXML file";

        content = FXCollections
                .observableArrayList(clientHandler.getListOfFiles());
        for(String str : content)
            System.out.println(str);
        filesListView.setItems(content); //this line here cases the error
```

//when commented out the application starts, but the button click causes an //error then
            assert filesListView != null : "filesListView was not initialized, check "
                    + "your FXML file";
        }

```
    @FXML
    public void onRefreshButtonClicked(MouseEvent event){
        filesListView.setItems(content);
    }
}
```

application class

```
package managefilesclientnetbeans;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ManageFilesClientNetBeans extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setTitle("Remote Files Client");
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(ManageFilesClientNetBeans.class.getResourceAsStream("images/synced.png")));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

stack trace due to the line

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/815033865.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/D:/vamk/TutorialWS/RESTAPIsWS/manageFilesClientNetBeans/dist/run1793002454/manageFilesClientNetBeans.jar!/managefilesclientnetbeans/FXMLDocument.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3208)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)
    at managefilesclientnetbeans.ManageFilesClientNetBeans.start(ManageFilesClientNetBeans.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/53700426.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/584634336.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1879407574.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/501263526.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/96639997.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and here is the stack trace from the button click

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1762)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3437)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$7900(Scene.java:3365)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3733)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/96639997.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1757)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at managefilesclientnetbeans.FXMLDocumentController.onRefreshButtonClicked(FXMLDocumentController.java:80)
    ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not define a `fx:id` in the fxml for your `filesListView`

Comment: thank you that was the problem, and after assigning the id, it works  .